# When calling process from SQLCLR, must the called process be 64bit?

Tags: sql-server, sqlclr

Suppose I want to call a 32 bit executable command from an SqlClr stored procedure running in Sql Server using something like the following bit of code:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text;

public partial class StoredProcedures
{
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlProcedure]
    public static void ecommerce_export_cmd(SqlString directoryPath,
                                            SqlString execName,
                                            SqlString arguments)
    {
        // Make sure the file exists
        string fullPath = Path.Combine(directoryPath.Value, execName.Value);
        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(fullPath);
        if (!fi.Exists)
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = string.Format(
                        "raiserror('File ->{0}<- is not found.',16,1)",
                          execName.Value);
                try { SqlContext.Pipe.ExecuteAndSend(cmd); }
                catch { return; }
            }
        }
        // ProcessStartInfo to run the DOS command attrib
        ProcessStartInfo pInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");
        pInfo.WorkingDirectory = directoryPath.Value;
        pInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
        // quote the arguments in case it has spaces
        pInfo.Arguments = string.Format("{0} {1}", execName.Value, arguments.Value);
        // Start a new process and wait for it to exit
        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo = pInfo;        
        process.Start();
        process.WaitForExit();
    }
}
```

Considering that SqlServer is a 64 bit process, given the code above, should I
expect potential problems due to the different bitness? I certainly don't want
to crash SqlServer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would expect that if there was going to be an issue that it would be indicated via an error message. In general, I would not think that you should need to worry about this as whatever process you start is not a part of SQL Server (hence only possible when the Assembly is marked as `UNSAFE`).

As it is, **cmd.exe** is a 64-bit app, and you don't need to exec **cmd.exe** in the first place when using `UseShellExecute = true`, you can just exec the command or app. **CMD** is a shell, and creating a new process with `UseShellExecute = true` is already calling **cmd.exe**.

Comment: I found some related information here: "32-bit processes cannot access the modules of a 64-bit process. If you try to get information about a 64-bit process from a 32-bit process, you will get a Win32Exception exception. A 64-bit process, on the other hand, can access the modules of a 32-bit process." I am not sure what they mean by "access the modules of...", but assuming they just mean overall that the 64bit sqlserver process can call out to a 32bit process without issue then hopefully things should be ok. Thanks @srutzky for clarifying that cmd.exe call isn't needed.

Comment: @Joe My guess is that "modules" refers to either DLLs and/or EXEs, whether they are loaded dynamically or explicitly executed (i.e. already in memory). P.S. I updated to clarify about CMD.EXE; it is only inherently there when using `UseShellExecute = true`. Running an EXE though does not require its own shell.